# Where's the best place to define a constant in a Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, constants

In a Ruby on Rails application, where is the best place to define a constant?

I have an array of constant data that I need available across all the controllers in my application.

Answer (score 66):

Rails >= 3, the application is itself a module (living in `config/application.rb`). You can store them in the application module

```
module MyApplication
  SUPER_SECRET_TOKEN = "123456"
end
```

Then use `MyApplication::SUPER_SECRET_TOKEN` to reference the constant.

---

Rails >= 2.1 && < 3 you should place them

1. in `/config/initializers` when the constant has the applications scope
2. when the constant refers to a specific model/controller/helper you can scope it within the class/module itself

---

Prior to Rails 2.1 and `initializers` support, programmers were used to place application constants in environment.rb.

Here's a few examples

```
# config/initializers/constants.rb
SUPER_SECRET_TOKEN = "123456"

# helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  THUMBNAIL_SIZE= "100x20"

  def thumbnail_tag(source, options = {})
    image_tag(source, options.merge(:size => THUMBNAIL_SIZE)
  end

end
```

Comment: strange, but doesn't work. Although constants.rb is executed on launch, I can't access SUPER_SECRET_TOKEN in controllers or views.

Comment: Now that's funny. Who'd know that 'uppercaseness' of those constants is enforced in rails?

Comment: Note: Don't forget to restart your server after making a new constant. Otherwise, it won't show up properly!

Comment: @NikitaRybak it's not because of Rails, it's a requirement of the Ruby language.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is this still the best approach for Rails 6? Another answer suggested `config.x`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34053451/144088

Answer (score 10):

You can place them in config/environment.rb:

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
    ...
    SITE_NAME = 'example.com'
end
```

If you have large amounts of global constants, this can be messy. Consider sourcing from a YAML file, or keeping the constants in the database.

EDIT:

weppos' answer is the better answer.

Keep your constants in a file in config/initializers/*.rb