# why does this variable in constants.rb need to be declared to be global?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, global-variables, constants

I want a list to be available to the whole application, so I put it in constants.rb:

`hebrew_consonants = ["א", "ב", "ג", "ד", "ה", "ו", "ז", "ח", "ט", "י", "ך", "כ", "ל","ם","מ","ן", "נ", "ס", "ע", "ף", "פ", "ץ", "צ", "ק", "ר", "ש","ת"]`

In application_controller.rb, I use the list as follows:

```
def is_hebrew?(query)
    (0...query.length).each do |index|
        return true if hebrew_consonants.include?(query[index])
    end
    return false
end
```

I restarted the server, and the app complained that it didn't know about the list.  I put dollar signs before its declaration and its reference ($hebrew_consonants), and it worked.  With my other constants, they just work.  I guess I thought they were *supposed* to be global variables just by virtue of being in that class.  Why is this one behaving differently?

Thank you

Comment: P.S. I know that list declaration looks wacky, but it's just from pasting the right-to-left characters, I think.  It does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure your `constants.rb` file is in `/config/initializers/`. Second, try using all caps for `hebrew_constants`. From the comments in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107782/wheres-the-best-place-to-define-a-constant-in-a-ruby-on-rails-application) it sounds like the all caps is necessary.

Comment: The all caps worked, I didn't realize that before, I was making the other constants all caps just as a convention.  Thanks